# How to delete folders from Library > Gradients in Motion 5

Tags: motion

I just installed Motion 5 but I've already run into a weird frustration. In the Library inspector I found a list of gradients. I clicked the `+` button at the bottom of the panel and discovered it creates folders. Ok. But now I have ended up with two folders I don't want and *I can't find any way to delete them*.

[image]

I have tried:

- right-clicking (no menu)
- selecting with mouse then `delete` or `backspace` keys
- looked through all the menus
- right-clicked on an actual gradient from the 'All' folder and revealed in finder... the folders do not show up in finder though

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the Folder
2. In the Motion Menu (at the top) go under "Edit" then select delete.